# How to correctly find the angle between two vectors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry

[image]

Is the angle between $\vec{P}$ & $\vec{Q}$ $150^{\circ}$ or $210^{\circ}$?

Comment: Why do you think one of these options is more correct than the other? What do you need this angle *for*?

Comment: Do you want the angle between P and Q or the angle between Q and P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering two "vectors" you should consider the shortest angle between them.Here it is 150°.                                                                                     Here the tails of the two vectors are touching in that case take the shortest angle same for the case where two heads are touching.
But in the case of 1st vector's head touching the other vector's tail it's different. See the image below
[image]
In this case you have to extend the underlying vector so that you can find the angle between the vectors,like this
[image]